# Probability arrangement questions with A, B, C, D, E, F

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) In how many ways can the letters a, b, c, d, e, f be
arranged so that the letters a and b are next to each
other?

(b) In how many ways can the letters a, b, c, d, e, f be
arranged so that the letters a and b are not next to
each other?

(c) In how many ways can the letters a, b, c, d, e, f be
arranged so that the letters a and b are next to each
other, but a and c are not.

Okay so for part (a) I said it was 5! * 2! = 240 combinations because I grouped AB as 2! and multiplied it by the rest of the combinations which I believe is 5!

For part (b) I used the same sort of equation 5! * 2! - 240 combinations again because its sort of the same question, but with different arrangements in a sense.

I'm not sure how to work out part (c)

I'm on here to ask if you guys think i'm right for part (a) and part (b), and if I am, could you please give me a hint as to how I should go about solving part (c). Thank you in advanced!

Comment: For part b the answer is $6!-240=480$.

Comment: Okay that was my second guess that I actually erased because I was unsure of it. Thank you! Any ideas for part C though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question (c), use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of arrangements of $\{ab ,c,d,e,f\}$, which is $5!$
- Include the number of arrangements of $\{ba ,c,d,e,f\}$, which is $5!$
- Exclude the number of arrangements of $\{cab  ,d,e,f\}$, which is $4!$
- Exclude the number of arrangements of $\{bac  ,d,e,f\}$, which is $4!$

The total number of arrangements is therefore $5!+5!-4!-4!=192$.